# FFMPEG overlay by time not working in my case

Tags: ffmpeg, android

**Image Overlay on image and enable by time**

```
ffmpeg -y -loop 1 -i .\1080.png -i .\021.jpg -i .\022.jpg -i .\023.jpg -filter_complex "  [1:v]scale=534:810[a]; [2:v]scale=534:810[b]; [3:v]scale=534:810[c]; [0:v][a] overlay=10:8:enable='between(t,0,8)'[o1]; [o1][b] overlay=264:778:enable='between(t,1,8)'[o2]; [o2][c]  overlay=534:1524:enable='between(t,2,8)'[o3]" -map "[o3]" -t 8 outImageOverlay.mp4
```

**Log**

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2021-01-01-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, png_pipe, from '.\1080.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1080x2340, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #1, image2, from '.\021.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 286665 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1080x2340, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, image2, from '.\022.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 337493 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1080x2340, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #3, image2, from '.\023.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 298403 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1080x2340, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (png) -> overlay:main
  Stream #1:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
  Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
  Stream #3:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 000001cd0b24d000] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001cd0b286080] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 000001cd0b2c9c40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] profile High, level 5.0, 4:2:0, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] 264 - core 161 r3027 4121277 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'outImageOverlay.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1080x2340, q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=  200 fps= 43 q=-1.0 Lsize=     208kB time=00:00:07.88 bitrate= 216.6kbits/s speed= 1.7x
video:205kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 1.538915%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] frame I:1     Avg QP:10.61  size: 68492
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] frame P:50    Avg QP:16.79  size:  2508
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] frame B:149   Avg QP:29.02  size:   104
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] consecutive B-frames:  0.5%  0.0%  1.5% 98.0%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] mb I  I16..4: 82.0% 10.1%  7.9%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] mb P  I16..4:  0.0%  0.5%  0.1%  P16..4:  1.0%  0.0%  0.1%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:98.2%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] mb B  I16..4:  0.0%  0.0%  0.0%  B16..8:  0.3%  0.0%  0.0%  direct: 0.0%  skip:99.7%  L0:39.1% L1:60.9% BI: 0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] 8x8 transform intra:28.0% inter:98.0%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 35.8% 31.1% 23.2% inter: 0.0% 0.1% 0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] i16 v,h,dc,p: 98%  1%  0%  1%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 19% 17% 15%  7%  7%  9%  8%  8% 11%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 18% 21%  9%  7% 10%  9% 11%  6%  9%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] i8c dc,h,v,p: 76% 10% 10%  4%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] ref P L0: 90.9%  0.7%  7.0%  1.3%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] ref B L0: 57.1% 42.0%  0.9%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] ref B L1: 93.2%  6.8%
[libx264 @ 000001cd0a848500] kb/s:209.46
```

**Overlay Video on Image Command**

```
ffmpeg -y -i love.mp4 -i .\1080.png -i .\021.jpg -i .\022.jpg -i .\023.jpg -loop 1 -i .\020.jpg -filter_complex " [2:v]scale=534:810[a]; [3:v]scale=534:810[b]; [4:v]scale=534:810[c]; [5:v]scale=8000:4000,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0020,1.5)':d=417:s=1080x2340,setsar=1[d]; [0:v]scale=1080x2340,setdar=1080:2340,colorkey=0x1CD51A:0.3:0.2[ckout]; [1:v][a] overlay=10:8:enable='between(t,0,8)'[o1]; [o1][b] overlay=264:778:enable='between(t,1,8)'[o2]; [o2][c]overlay=534:1524:enable='between(t,2,8)'[o3]; [d][o3]overlay[o4]; [o4][ckout]overlay[o5]" -map "[o5]" -pix_fmt yuvj422p -t 8 outvideoOverlayInImage.mp4
```

**Log**

```
ffmpeg version 4.3.1-2021-01-01-essentials_build-www.gyan.dev Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 10.2.0 (Rev5, Built by MSYS2 project)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-static --disable-w32threads --disable-autodetect --enable-fontconfig --enable-iconv --enable-gnutls --enable-libxml2 --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-zlib --enable-libsrt --enable-libssh --enable-libzmq --enable-avisynth --enable-sdl2 --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libaom --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libvpx --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libzimg --enable-amf --enable-cuda-llvm --enable-cuvid --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-nvdec --enable-nvenc --enable-d3d11va --enable-dxva2 --enable-libmfx --enable-libgme --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libtheora --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libgsm --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopus --enable-libspeex --enable-libvorbis --enable-librubberband
  libavutil      56. 51.100 / 56. 51.100
  libavcodec     58. 91.100 / 58. 91.100
  libavformat    58. 45.100 / 58. 45.100
  libavdevice    58. 10.100 / 58. 10.100
  libavfilter     7. 85.100 /  7. 85.100
  libswscale      5.  7.100 /  5.  7.100
  libswresample   3.  7.100 /  3.  7.100
  libpostproc    55.  7.100 / 55.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'love.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    creation_time   : 2021-08-17T05:35:07.000000Z
    com.android.version: 11
  Duration: 00:00:06.93, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 538 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 196 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-08-17T05:35:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : SoundHandle
    Stream #0:1(eng): Video: h264 (Baseline) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt470bg/smpte170m), 1080x2340, 334 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 6:13, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2021-08-17T05:35:07.000000Z
      handler_name    : VideoHandle
Input #1, png_pipe, from '.\1080.png':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #1:0: Video: png, rgba(pc), 1080x2340, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #2, image2, from '.\021.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 286665 kb/s
    Stream #2:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1080x2340, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #3, image2, from '.\022.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 337493 kb/s
    Stream #3:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1080x2340, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #4, image2, from '.\023.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 298403 kb/s
    Stream #4:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1080x2340, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Input #5, image2, from '.\020.jpg':
  Duration: 00:00:00.04, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 184663 kb/s
    Stream #5:0: Video: mjpeg (Baseline), yuvj444p(pc, bt470bg/unknown/unknown), 1080x2340, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 25 tbn, 25 tbc
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:1 (h264) -> scale
  Stream #1:0 (png) -> overlay:main
  Stream #2:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
  Stream #3:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
  Stream #4:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
  Stream #5:0 (mjpeg) -> scale
  overlay -> Stream #0:0 (libx264)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[swscaler @ 00000230595cff40] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 0000023059727e80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 00000230597768c0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 00000230597c3c80] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[swscaler @ 00000230597faec0] No accelerated colorspace conversion found from yuv420p to argb.
[swscaler @ 0000023059884cc0] deprecated pixel format used, make sure you did set range correctly
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] using SAR=1/1
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] using cpu capabilities: MMX2 SSE2Fast SSSE3 SSE4.2 AVX FMA3 BMI2 AVX2
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] profile High 4:2:2, level 5.0, 4:2:2, 8-bit
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] 264 - core 161 r3027 4121277 - H.264/MPEG-4 AVC codec - Copyleft 2003-2020 - http://www.videolan.org/x264.html - options: cabac=1 ref=3 deblock=1:0:0 analyse=0x3:0x113 me=hex subme=7 psy=1 psy_rd=1.00:0.00 mixed_ref=1 me_range=16 chroma_me=1 trellis=1 8x8dct=1 cqm=0 deadzone=21,11 fast_pskip=1 chroma_qp_offset=-2 threads=6 lookahead_threads=1 sliced_threads=0 nr=0 decimate=1 interlaced=0 bluray_compat=0 constrained_intra=0 bframes=3 b_pyramid=2 b_adapt=1 b_bias=0 direct=1 weightb=1 open_gop=0 weightp=2 keyint=250 keyint_min=25 scenecut=40 intra_refresh=0 rc_lookahead=40 rc=crf mbtree=1 crf=23.0 qcomp=0.60 qpmin=0 qpmax=69 qpstep=4 ip_ratio=1.40 aq=1:1.00
Output #0, mp4, to 'outvideoOverlayInImage.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : mp42
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: isommp42
    com.android.version: 11
    encoder         : Lavf58.45.100
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (libx264) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuvj422p(pc), 1080x2340 [SAR 1:1 DAR 6:13], q=-1--1, 25 fps, 12800 tbn, 25 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc58.91.100 libx264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
frame=  200 fps= 11 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1411kB time=00:00:07.88 bitrate=1467.1kbits/s speed=0.435x
video:1408kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.226583%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] frame I:1     Avg QP:20.68  size:121139
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] frame P:50    Avg QP:20.09  size: 15622
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] frame B:149   Avg QP:24.04  size:  3617
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] consecutive B-frames:  0.5%  0.0%  1.5% 98.0%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] mb I  I16..4:  8.9% 81.4%  9.7%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] mb P  I16..4:  1.5%  1.9%  0.3%  P16..4: 21.8%  8.1%  4.7%  0.0%  0.0%    skip:61.6%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] mb B  I16..4:  0.1%  0.1%  0.0%  B16..8: 26.8%  0.7%  0.1%  direct: 0.3%  skip:72.1%  L0:46.3% L1:53.3% BI: 0.3%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] 8x8 transform intra:59.8% inter:84.9%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] coded y,uvDC,uvAC intra: 30.0% 30.8% 13.5% inter: 3.0% 2.2% 0.1%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] i16 v,h,dc,p: 66% 30%  2%  2%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] i8 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 29% 12% 43%  3%  3%  3%  3%  2%  3%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] i4 v,h,dc,ddl,ddr,vr,hd,vl,hu: 39% 19% 11%  5%  6%  5%  6%  4%  5%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] i8c dc,h,v,p: 57% 19% 21%  3%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] Weighted P-Frames: Y:0.0% UV:0.0%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] ref P L0: 73.3% 11.4%  8.9%  6.4%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] ref B L0: 96.2%  3.1%  0.7%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] ref B L1: 95.5%  4.5%
[libx264 @ 00000230536e2900] kb/s:1441.17
```

- [020.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUp4K.jpg)
- [021.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XesRk.jpg)
- [022.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLyR0.jpg)
- [023.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hkLtB.jpg)
- [1080.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uv275.jpg)
- [outImageOverlay](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgyY5.jpg)
- [outvideoOverlayInImage.mp4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hPs1h.jpg)
- [love.mp4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/23Jdx.jpg)

Comment: "not working" is not descriptive of the actual problem. The actual problem is therefore unknown. This means we are unable to provide help. Describe the problem and copy and paste all of the text from the log.

Comment: Hello Mr @llogan Sir I posted log and input files. please  check the problem of overlaying by time thank you.

Comment: That's better, but now you need to explain 1) What is the desired result? 2) What is the actual result and how is it different than what you want?

Comment: Hello Sir @llogan I want to create image slide show and overlay green screen video into created image slide show and slide show is not working overlay by time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `-loop 1` before each JPG:

```
ffmpeg -y -i love.mp4 -i .\1080.png -loop 1 -i .\021.jpg -loop 1 -i .\022.jpg -loop 1 -i .\023.jpg -loop 1 -i .\020.jpg -filter_complex " [2:v]scale=534:810[a]; [3:v]scale=534:810[b]; [4:v]scale=534:810[c]; [5:v]scale=8000:4000,zoompan=z='min(zoom+0.0020,1.5)':d=417:s=1080x2340,setsar=1[d]; [0:v]scale=1080x2340,setdar=1080:2340,colorkey=0x1CD51A:0.3:0.2[ckout]; [1:v][a] overlay=10:8:enable='between(t,0,8)'[o1]; [o1][b] overlay=264:778:enable='between(t,1,8)'[o2]; [o2][c]overlay=534:1524:enable='between(t,2,8)'[o3]; [d][o3]overlay[o4]; [o4][ckout]overlay[o5]" -map "[o5]" -pix_fmt yuvj422p -t 8 outvideoOverlayInImage.mp4
```

Comment: Thank you @llogan Sir, can you please describe the reason behind to adding -loop 1.

Comment: @PatelMilan Without looping the image is treated as 1 frame so the `'between(t,1,8)'` would be ineffective.

Comment: Hello Mr. @llogan I am using this command to overlay into videos ```ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -i overlay.png -filter_complex overlay=0:0 -strict -2 -c:a copy -flags +global_header -qscale:v 3 output.mp4``` 
When sending on iphone the audio is muted problem give the solution regarding this command Thank you